# How can i take input from bootstrap switch using jinja2 for WTForms?

Tags: validation, flask, jinja2, bootstrap-5, flask-wtforms

```
<form>
 <div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Default switch checkboxinput</label>
 </div>
 <div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckChecked" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckChecked">Checked switch checkbox input</label>
 </div>
</form>
```

[check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy5b4.png)

I want to validate this form for my flaskapp. By default this switch should not checked and if any user checked it than i want to enable some feature.

Answer (score 0):

You create a form in which you extend `FlaskForm` and use a field of type `BooleanField`. Within the template you can control the appearance using the `class_` attribute. Whether the user pressed the switch can be found using the data in the form field.
If the value of the form field should be set in advance, it is possible to set a value using the `data` attribute of the form, which expects a dict, or using an attribute with the identifier of the field.

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import BooleanField

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'your secret here'

class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    feature = BooleanField('Default switch checkboxinput')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = MyForm(feature=True)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print(form.feature.data)
    return render_template('index.html', **locals())
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Index</title>
    <link 
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        rel="stylesheet" 
        integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" 
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <main class="container mt-3">
        <form method="POST">
            {{ form.csrf_token }}
            <div class="form-check form-switch">
                {{ form.feature(class_='form-check-input') }}
                {{ form.feature.label(class_='form-check-label') }}
            </div>
            <div class="mt-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </main>

    <script 
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" 
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

To submit the entire form without using a button, you can use a `change` event. If the user changes the position of a switch, it is fired and the form can be sent.

```html
<script>
    (function() {
        const elems = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
        elems.forEach(elem => {
            elem.addEventListener('change', () => {
                elem.form.submit();
            });
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: is this possible without a button? I want the switch behave like a button.

Comment: You may be able to use JavaScript to catch an event, then submit the entire form, thus removing the submit button.

Comment: @MahfuzurRahman I've added a simple example to the answer, which you'll probably need to adapt to your needs.

Comment: It is submitting perfectly. One more thing is that if user checked the switch how can I set it to checked until they turn it off again? Thanks.

Comment: @MahfuzurRahman I have adjusted my answer.